# Single application tile showing multiple times in SAP Fiori launchpad

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori

I am using the SAP Fiori Launchpad as portal.In launchpad single application tile showing two times.There is only single App and catalog in cloud platform.

[image]

After Deleting App from Cockpit and redeploy the same App, then one tile Error tile appear on Fiori launchpad
[image]

Comment: Do you have access to your `catalogs` definition file? Can you post it here?

Comment: Catalog name : Clearing Instruction      .How to fetch catalog definition file?

Answer (score 1):

Could be two reasons:

1. Authorization role is assigned to tile "A" but not to tile "B". As long as you have tile "A" it provides authorization to tile "B". If you delete it, tile "B" has no authorization.
2. Target mapping is assigned to one tile but not the other. Similar case, you delete one with mapping and leave other without access.

Take care!

Answer (score 0):

Probably is an error of launchpad's configuration. If you refresh(CTRL+F5) launchpad you see just 1 tile for app. If a tile show Error is why has loose its reference, for example target mapping(semantic Object and action) or the tile.

Have a nice day